# Send email as PDF in ruby on rails in Typo3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, printing, typo3

I have an web-application in RoR which calculates some energy values and investment money. I use ajax to send the data from the web-browser to the server. It is something like this: `Browser-server-Browser-Server-Browser`

This web-application is already integrated in typo3 and I want to implement a PDF button to send the results per email (in other words, a photo of the page with the results).

I have heard an option would be to generate some links in RoR to be used in typo3 (when clicking on it, it would open exactly the web-application with the results already calculated). But as a newbie, I do not really know which would be the best approach.

Any recommendation?

Comment: How have you done the integration of typo3 and ruby on rails? And which system should send the emails?

Comment: If you just want the web page as a pdf you could look at something like [`wicked_pdf`](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) which can take html and turn it into a nice pdf without too much effort

Comment: @Meier the integration was done by another company. It was recommended to me to "generate some links" and then this could be used in typo3 to send the emails, but at the moment I really do not.

Comment: come on, what is integrated in what? do they share a database? is one thing in a iframe of the other? or are they not integrated at all, just sharing a server or a domain? who sends emails? When you want to solve a problem, you need first understand things like this.

Comment: Sorry sir if I am not able at the moment to understand this. As I put in my question "This web-application is already integrated in typo3 ", that means rails in typo3. I have nothing to do with typo3(I havent touched it) since it was doing by a third-party, I just started since some months with rails (in general in this web-world) and sorry if my level is not like yours. I just wanted some indications, tipps to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot of the page can be done client-side:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

You could even have another page with the same results that you use only for the rendering of the result page what you use for making a clean screen-shot (you might not want to have the  footer, menu and other elements on that page, only the results)

Once you have your screenshot, you can upload it to your server where you can use it to create a PDF of that image and then send it with any mail API you prefer to use.

info about TYPO3's mail api can be found here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html